# Susy: Omega and Responsive Grids

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

When using Susy, you put an "omega" flag on the last item of a row to remove its `margin-right`. For example, let's say we have a bunch of items we need to lay out on a 12-column grid:

```
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">I'm the last of the row</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

And the SCSS:

```
.item{
  @include span-columns(4);
  @include nth-omega(3n);
}
```

But our grid is responsive, and smaller displays use an 8-column grid. The problem is that `omega` now needs to appear on `2n`, and not `3n`:

```
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">I'm the last of the row</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

So my question is: with Susy, do you need to redefine your columns for each breakpoint, or is there some way to define column widths once and for all and let the `omega` naturally fall at the right place?

And if not, does any other grid system offer that?

Comment: Note that this question has nothing to do with the Drupal Omega theme, sorry if the title was misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solving your issue with Susy

Susy allows overriding the number of columns. Many Susy mixins allow that — every mixin that accepts the `$context` argument.

But the best way to override a context is with the `at-breakpoint` mixin:

```css
// Defining the breakpoints
$mobile-to-medium: 400px;
$medium-to-large:  800px;

// Defining columns
$columns-small:    1;
$columns-medium:   8;
$columns-large:    12;

// Starting with a one-column mobile grid
$total-columns: $columns-small;

// Global styles go here

// Mobile-only styles
@include at-breakpoint($total-columns $mobile-to-medium) {
  // ...
}

// Medium-only styles go here
@include at-breakpoint($mobile-to-medium $columns-medium $medium-to-large) {

  .item{
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include nth-omega(2n); } }

// Large-only styles go here
@include at-breakpoint($medium-to-large $columns-large) {

  .item{
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include nth-omega(3n); } }
```

Omega supposes layered responsiveness: mobile styles are applied to all widths; medium styles are applied to medium and large widths, large styles are applied to large widths.

The approach above is not layered: mobile styles are applied only to mobile width, etc. This way you don't need to worry about omega applied where it's not supposed to go.

To use the Omega layered approach, just remove the third element (max-width) in `at-breakpoint` calls. But then you have to apply `@include remove-nth-omega()`:

```css
// Defining the breakpoints
$mobile-to-medium: 400px;
$medium-to-large:  800px;

// Defining columns
$columns-small:    1;
$columns-medium:   8;
$columns-large:    12;

// Starting with a one-column mobile grid
$total-columns: $columns-small;

// Global styles go here

// Medium and large styles go here
@include at-breakpoint($mobile-to-medium $columns-medium) {

  .item{
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include nth-omega(2n); } }

// Large-only styles go here
@include at-breakpoint($medium-to-large $columns-large) {

  .item{
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include remove-nth-omega(2n);
    @include nth-omega(3n); } }
```

### An overview of an omega-less approach

There are SASS grid systems that don't use the "omega" parameter (not to be confused with the Omega theme for Drupal) that's necessary to be applied for the last item in each row. Instead, you provide each element's position (which column the item starts at) in addition to its column width.

To make that possible, another CSS positioning [approach](http://www.palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret) is used, known as "isolation". The first framework to use this approach was [Zen Grids](http://zengrids.com/).

Susy also has support for this method with its `isolate` and `isolate-grid` [mixins](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-isolate).

This overview would not be complete without mentioning [Singularity](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki), the latest and most advanced SASS grid framework. It supports both postioning methods and is extendable to support more in the future (like [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) which has recently been [added](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/921) to Compass).

Comment: The first code sample here demonstrates what @Kaishin suggested above, with more specific media-queries. The second sample demonstrates the `remove-nth-omega()` option. Isolation would also work, but has similar caveats - you would still have to adjust to different grids.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you will have to redefine the total number of columns (context) in the new breakpoint. As for `nth-omega`, you can use `@include remove-nth-omega(3n)` to negate the first call before explicitly calling the second, but I consider that a CSS code smell (having to neutralize properties) so I recommend using media-query splitting to avoid that.

Also, I'm not aware of any framework that can automatically do that for you.

Comment: `remove-nth-omega(3n)` is the right tool for the job, if you don't mind a bit of override code. Otherwise @Kaishin is right, you can use more specific (min + max) media-queries to remove any need for the override.